# Two associations between same tables with Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I have an app with Two Models **Stadium** & **Team**, they have a many-to-many relationship and are joined in the middle by a join table.

My current structure looks like this:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :stadiumteams, :class_name => 'StadiumTeam'
    has_many :stadiums, :through => :stadiumteams
end

class Stadium < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :stadiumteams, :class_name => 'StadiumTeam'
    has_many :teams, :through => :stadiumteams
end

class StadiumTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :stadium
    belongs_to :team
end
```

This relationship show “current residents for a stadium”. But now I also want to have a relationship that can display old residents.

For example Tottenham (Team) used to play at White Hart Lane (Stadium) But now play at (Wembley) Stadium.

I am planning to do the following. But I am unsure if this will work or if there is a better way to do it?

Team

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :stadiumteams, :class_name => 'StadiumTeam'
    has_many :stadiums, :through => :stadiumteams

    #has_many :oldstadiums, :class_name => 'OldStadium'
    #has_many :stadiums, :through => :oldstadiums
end
```

Stadium

```
class Stadium < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :stadiumteams, :class_name => 'StadiumTeam'
    has_many :teams, :through => :stadiumteams

    #has_many :oldstadiums, :class_name => 'OldStadium'
    #has_many :teams, :through => :oldstadiums
end
```

New Join Table

```
class OldStadium < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :stadium
    belongs_to :team
end
```

Any help is very appreciated!

EDIT: (Input fields)
Here's how the code for my inputs currently looks:

```
<%= f.association :teams, label: 'Current Residents', class:'select2-field', placeholder: "Select teams", collection: @teams, input_html: { multiple: true }, hint: 'Select one or multiple teams.'%>

<%= f.association :teams, label: 'Old Residents', class:'select2-field', placeholder: "Select teams", collection: @teams, input_html: { multiple: true }, hint: 'Select one or multiple teams.' %>
```

And my params

```
   def stadium_params
      params.require(:stadium).permit(:name, :capacity, :city, :country, :location_name, :address, :longitude, :latitude, :image, :surface, :official_opening_date, :cost, :web_url, :also_known_as, :record_attendance, :team_ids => [])
    end
```

Comment: You can add start & end date columns on the join table, so when a `StadiumTeam` record has a start but no end date it means "this team is current resident for this stadium", and you can guess the meaning if an end date is present. To define the two relations in Rails (current & previous "resident" teams), you can add a lambda to your relation: `has_many :current_stadiums, ->{ where(stadium_teams: { end_date: nil }) }, through: :stadiumteams` and about the same for `previous_stadiums` but with a `end_date is not null`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your quick response. Actually, I already have a Boolean column called current_home fin my StadiumTeam Table. So maybe I could have two input fields where one sets the boolean to true (if current home) and the other field set the value to false (if not current home)?

But I'm not sure how I would accomplish that. Added the code for my inputs to the original post.

Comment: I suggest you to use DateTime fields as they can act as Boolean by their presence, but bring more information. A Boolean gives you the smallest amount of data you can get, whereas a DateTime field tells you the same answer but with more data. In your context, if you want to build the history of all the Stadiums the Team XX has been resident, well you can't do it with the Boolean columns, but you can do it easily with the DateTime columns.

Comment: You have several options, the one I would suggest is to define the 2 relations based on that Boolean, so `Stadium` `has_many :old_teams, -> { where(stadiumteams: { current_home: false }) }, through: :stadiumteams, class_name: 'Stadium'`. Then you can do in your HTML form `f.association :old_stadiums [...]` and it should set this `current_home` to `false` automatically

Comment: Yeah, that is a good point. Just want adding new stadiums to be a very easy process, and I also want to be able to add teams in bulk in case one stadium has many teams. And in many cases I would not have the information of "end date", so the information would not be very accurate.

With that said. I'm pretty new to Programming and if your advice is to use DateTime I would consider it.

Comment: If your application is just a small project that is not meant to grow largely and be extensively used & expanded, then a simple Boolean can do the job. To accomplish this work (using Boolean), you can check my previous comment with `f.association :old_stadiums`

Comment: Thanks! 

Added the has_many :old teams code but I get an error: "Association :old_stadiums not found" 

Do I also need to update the team model, to say has_many old_stadiums or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define relations with a lambda to append an additional `where` clause in the relation:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :stadiumteams, :class_name => 'StadiumTeam'

    has_many stadiums, :through => :stadiumteams
    has_many :current_stadiums, ->{ where(stadiumteams: { current_home: true }) }, :through => :stadiumteams, :class_name => 'Stadium', :source => :stadium
    has_many :previous_stadiums, ->{ where(stadiumteams: { current_home: false }) }, :through => :stadiumteams, :class_name =>'Stadium', :source => :stadium
end

class Stadium < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :stadiumteams, :class_name => 'StadiumTeam'

    has_many :teams, :through => :stadiumteams
    has_many :current_teams, ->{ where(stadiumteams: { current_home: true }) }, :through => :stadiumteams, :class_name => 'Team', :source => :team
    has_many :previous_teams, ->{ where(stadiumteams: { current_home: false }) }, :through => :stadiumteams, :class_name =>'Team'. :source => :team
end

class StadiumTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :stadium
    belongs_to :team
end
```

And then you should be able to do (in rails console):

```
team = Team.first
stadium = Stadium.first
team.previous_stadiums <<
team.save
team.reload.previous_stadiums.include?(stadium) 
# => should return true
```

So this way you can simply use in your UI a input for the association `:previous_teams` and `:current_teams`:

```
f.association :current_teams, #...
```

Comment: Thanks. But get an error in console when i do the 3rd command. >>>

"ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) "previous_stadium" or :previous_stadiums in model StadiumTeam. Try 'has_many :previous_stadiums, :through => :stadiumteams, :source => <name>'. Is it one of stadium or team?"

Comment: @tommers I updated my answer to include the `source` options in the `has_many`

Comment: Thanks again. But now I get: (still on 3rd command)

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'stadium_id' for Stadium.

Comment: And when I do it with f.association :current_stadiums, in the _form partial i get:

"Association :current_stadiums not found"

Comment: I updated my answer with a fix for the rails console code and for the `f.association` part too

Comment: Thanks again :) Still got an error tough.. this time when I type: "team.save"

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Stadium(#70286939583480) expected, got TrueClass(#70286926329100)

But now the form page doesn't crash!

Comment: Managed to solve this error by setting  'config.cache_classes = true' in development.rb

Comment: I assume I also need to add something to my create method in StadiumController right? Previously I only saved :team_ids => [] to the stadium_params.

Comment: Ok, nvm. Added  :current_team_ids => [], :previous_team_ids => [] to my params and that seemed to do it! :)

Comment: Sorry for spamming. Just wanted to say I got it working! Big thank you for all help @MrYoshiji

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to fulfill your requirement. Your approach also enough, but for efficiency, since the number of Stadium is small ( thousands ), you can use STI for `Stadium` entity.

```
class Stadium < ActiveRecord::
  has_many :stadiums_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :stadiums_teams
end

class OldStadium < Stadium; end

class RecentStadium < Stadium; end

class StadiumTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stadium
  belongs_to :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stadiums_teams
  has_many :stadiums, through: :stadiums_teams, source: :stadium
  has_many :old_stadiums, through: :stadiums_teams,
    source: :stadium, class_name: OldStadium.name
  has_many :recent_stadiums, through: :stadiums_teams,
    source: :stadium, class_name: RecentStadium.name
end
```

So, in most case, you will work with `OldStadium` / `RecentStadium` model, but when you want to check if a team ever played at a specific stadium or not, just use `Stadium` model.